# SSH config for hostname read from file

Tags: linux, ssh

The setup is as follows:

- **Local PC** from which I want to ssh into…
- **Gateway node `gateway`** which is an intermediate node which is only used to ssh into…
- **Front node `front`**, again an intermediate node, required to ssh into the final…
- **Compute node**, which is the node I actually want to use

I want to setup my local ssh config such that I can directly type `ssh compute`.

**The problem:** As opposed to `gateway` and `front`, the hostname for the compute node is not static (i.e. it may change multiple times in one day). I have a script `compute_node_hostname.sh` on `front` which will output the name of the compute node, i.e. `node339`. How can I use it in my config?

The following simple config with the compute node hardcoded does work:

```
Host gateway front compute
    User …
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host front
    HostName front
    ProxyJump gateway

Host compute
    HostName node339
    ProxyJump front
```

**Constraint:** I cannot use `RemoteCommand` in my config

Answer (score 1):

Recall that 'ProxyJump' is a smarter version of 'ProxyCommand' – it does some additional work with copying the options specified in CLI, but essentially it's the same as:

```
Host compute
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p front
```

where `%h` and `%p` are automatically expanded to the requested hostname and port.

So the way you can use a dynamic hostname is by replacing the `%h` parameter:

```
Host compute
    ProxyCommand ssh -W $(compute_node_hostname.sh):%p front
```

Note: This won't play nicely with nodes having different hostkeys. Since you're connecting through another host that's already on the remote network, it should be safe to just disable hostkey verification for this hop.

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I forgot to mention that the script is located on the `front` node, not my local PC. It seems like the ProxyCommand tries to access the script locally. Is there any way to change that?

Comment: The usual answer would be `$(ssh front compute_node_hostname.sh)`, but since you ruled out RemoteCommand already, there's not really any other way to run commands remotely on `front`, is there?

Comment: If I use the `$(ssh …)` for the `-W` flag, I always get the following error:
`Bad packet length 1349676916.
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to UNKNOWN port 65535: message authentication code incorrect`
It also doesn't work if I copy the ssh command into a local script and call it instead. Any clue?

Comment: Does the 'inner' ssh command work all by itself? And does `ssh -W the_hostname:22 front` work if you expand the hostname "by hand"? (It should output _nothing more_ than the "SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_whatever" handshake message.)

Comment: The inner command correctly outputs `node339`. The `ssh -W node339:22 gateway` outputs the SSH string alongside a stderr login message from the server. The same happens for `ssh -W $(ssh front compute_node_hostname.sh):22 gateway`. The `ssh compute` works as expected if I remove the inner ssh call from my config, i.e. `ProxyCommand ssh -W $(echo node339):%p front`